# Is there any possibility for one rserve's client to share workspace with another?

Tags: r, rserve

I'd like replace [RExcel](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html#RExcel) with the [Excelsi-R](http://sourceforge.net/p/excelsir/wiki/User%20Documentation/). Excelsi-R talks R via [RServe](https://rforge.net/Rserve/index.html), and RServe has this feature, that makes each client work in independent workspaces.

What I want is to actually *share* a single workspace between at least 2 simultaneously connected clients. One client would be run by Excelsi-R, and another by manually launched interactive R Session. That would allow me to interface with the Excelsi-R session in traditional way (say, in RStudio).

I don't need asynchronous computation; I'm perfectly happy if Excelsi-R would have to wait, until a command issued by the other connection finishes, and vice versa; just like in the RExcel "foreground mode".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, since each process has exactly one connection. There are a few hacks - such as you can "switch" sessions by starting a listener for another connection in an existing session - but that may be a bit too limited.

That said, it is technically possible (Rserve support looping over multiple connections - it is used in RCloud to support two separate processes on one connection) - the challenge is how to link two independent connections to a single process. The `rsio` communication was added in Rserve 1.8 specifically to allow the passing of descriptors between Rserve instances, but it was not used so far. If there is interest in that kind of functionality, I can see how it could be added.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I am interested. It will greatly facilitate the process of writing and debugging remote and interactive R computations with Excel front end.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97637/ad-is-there-any-possibility-for-one-rserves-client-to-share-workspace-with-anot